# When calling a JPanel to run from a button clicked from another class running a JFrame, it only displays the JFrame of the other class not panel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, calling-convention, game-loop

The Game class calling the window class int he constructor the print it's contents on a JFrame.

```
public class Game extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public Game() {
        initComponents();
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                player.keyReleased(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                player.keyPressed(e);
            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);
        new Window(this);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Game();
    }
```

The Window class...

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

public Window(Game game) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Final Gunner");
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    while (true) {
        try {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
} }
```

In another class with a JFrame called "GameMenu", I call the Game class by "new Game();" when a button is clicked, however it only displays a blank frame, nothing else but if I call the Game class by "new Game();" in another class in the main method it will run perfectly, why is this so?

Comment: Do you have any exception stack trace? what's the output on the console of your app?

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing displaying in the console.

Comment: To save time and effort post an [MCVE]. This will answer many open questions like: 1.  where is `player` defined ? 2. what is the use of `main` posted ?  3. `Game` is empty. What do you expect to see ?

Comment: Your Window class is trying to be a JFrame and a timing loop.  Separate those functions.  In general, when creating a Java Swing game, use the model / view / controller pattern.  A Window is part of the view and a timing loop is one of the controllers.